# Android Delay For Loop Inside Each Iteration

Tags: android

I Have the following code:

```
                    Timer timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        public void run() {
                            for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {

                                Log.d("LOG", "i: " + i);
                            }
                        }
                    }, 5000);
```

I would like to increment I from 0 up to 10 with a delay of 5 seconds with each increment inside the loop.

Currently, the code executes after 5 seconds and runs the for loop asynchronous instead of waiting 5 seconds in between each interaction. This code should take about a minute to complete.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the handler

```
int i = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(i<11)
             {
               Log.d("LOG", "i: " + i);
               i++;
            }else
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);


            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    };
    //Start Handler
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
```

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you

Comment: the Logcat logs 1 and then after 5 seconds it logs 10 continuously..

Answer (score 1):

OK so to iterate inside a for loop with a delay I used `Thread.sleep` but this will cause the app to become blank until it finished executing the for loop because it runs on UI. To overcome this I run the thread.sleep in background. Full code below:

```
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                        Log.d("LOG", "i: "+i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            }
        }).start();
```